# In which case GSU can be greater than RSU (during the Voice call charging - diameter protocol)?

Tags: call, sip, voice, diameter-protocol

Is there any voice call or any other diameter charging scenario in which 'Granted Service Unit' (GSU) can be more than 'Requested Service Unit' (RSU) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is possible when subscriber uses less than the minimum charge interval, and when next time it sends CCR-Update request, our charging system should be able to grant requested quota + balance quota which we charged in previous call. i.e.

1) Initial quota request = 300 sec, 
2) granted 300 sec, 
3) Used - 4 sec (but minimum charge interval is 5 sec)

In this case when next time system re-request quota for 300 sec, charging system should grant 300 + 1 sec from previous balance.

Not sure if there is any other case where GSU > RSU